# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getForeignKey()

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I am using datatables server side and have just upgraded to Laravel 5.4 and I get the above error ... It seems to have something to do with eager loading ...

```
[2017-01-26 09:32:16] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getForeignKey() in /var/www/html/odie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2508
Stack trace:

    0 /var/www/html/odie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1322): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('getForeignKey', Array)

    1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('getForeignKey', Array)

    2 /var/www/html/odie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php(331): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

    3 /var/www/html/odie/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/Engines/QueryBuilderEngine.php(544): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation->__call('getForeignKey', Array)

    4 /var/www/html/odie/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/Engines/QueryBuilderEngine.php(639): Yajra\Datatables\Engines\QueryBuilderEngine->joinEagerLoadedColumn('visi_patn', 'name')

    5 /var/www/html/odie/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/Engines/BaseEngine.php(611): Yajra\Datatables\Engines\QueryBuilderEngine->ordering()

    6 /var/www/html/odie/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/Engines/BaseEngine.php(595): Yajra\Datatables\Engines\BaseEngine->orderRecords(false)

    7 /var/www/html/odie/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/Engines/QueryBuilderEngine.php(77): Yajra\Datatables\Engines\BaseEngine->make(true, false)
```

Comment: Your post doesn't exactly match the Stackoverflow guidelines. For starters, there is no question in your post. And another thing is, your question doesn't seem to be a programming problem.

Comment: OK ... Thanks for the input ... Ill go thru the tour carefully ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its difficult to answer in full for your question only by looking at the stack trace without looking at the implementation.

But from the looks of it you are calling `getForeignKey()` method on a `builder` but actually what you should've done is

```
Model::getForeignKey()
```